# How to get season and if a date range falls on a US Holiday with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that has 2 columns named date_x and date_y. I want to pull what season date_x is in (winter, spring, summer, or fall) in a separate column and then determine if a holiday falls with the range of dates exclusive of date_y. I have seen some potential solutions around that have done seasons by breaking down the year into days but I can't seem to make that work for me. I am still figuring out what pandas can do. Another problem I am faced with is how to account for holidays like Easter that change every year. Any help is truly appreciated.

I have also played around with trying to make [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139306/determine-season-given-timestamp-in-python-using-datetime/28686747#28686747) work for me but can't figure out how to adapt it to create a new column that works off of date_x instead of today's date

Below is an image of what I am striving for.

[image: Date_x, Date_y, what season Date_x is in, What holiday, if any, is within the range of dates, exclusive of Date_y]

Comment: The hardest part of this solution is the `Holiday` column output, but I think there is a specific library for that for US Holidays: https://www.geeks forgeeks.org/python-holidays-library/

Comment: Yeah, that was my feeling too. I had no idea that there was a holiday python library though so that might come in handy, I still have trouble getting functions to work with pandas columns though. I don't know if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have a dataframe with dates that not only range multiple holidays, but they range multiple seasons:

```
        Date_x      Date_y
0   2020-12-22  2021-01-01
1   2020-06-20  2020-07-11
3   2020-02-11  2020-03-27
4   2020-05-22  2020-06-27
```

In order to get 1. `Season` and 2. `Holiday`:

1. I built off the link you shared to customize seasons
2. I tried to avoid "third-party" libraries and chose to use the `USFederalHolidayCalendar` from the `pandas` `holiday` library; because, I thought that would be more reliable; however, I do not have much experieince with holiday libraries. Also, there are multiple `calendars` that could be used from the pandas library. From there, I used the `get_season(x)` and `get_holiday()` function that I created. For the former, I would reference the link in your question, and the latter uses list comprehension to pull in holidays into your dataframe from the `holidays` dataframe I created.

---

```
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
holidays = (pd.DataFrame(cal.holidays(return_name=True), columns=['Holiday'])
            .reset_index()
            .rename({'index': 'Date'}, axis=1))
holidays['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(holidays['Date'])
df= pd.DataFrame({'Date_x': {0: '2020-12-22', 1: '2020-06-20', 2: '2020-02-11', 3: '2020-05-22'},
                  'Date_y': {0: '2021-01-01', 1: '2020-07-11', 2: '2020-03-27', 3: '2020-06-27'}})
df['Date_x'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_x'])
df['Date_y'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_y'])

Y = 2000 # dummy leap year to allow input X-02-29 (leap day)
seasons = [('Winter', (date(Y,  1,  1),  date(Y,  3, 20))),
           ('Spring', (date(Y,  3, 21),  date(Y,  6, 20))),
           ('Summer', (date(Y,  6, 21),  date(Y,  9, 22))),
           ('Fall', (date(Y,  9, 23),  date(Y, 12, 20))),
           ('Winter', (date(Y, 12, 21),  date(Y, 12, 31)))]

def get_season(x):
    x = x.replace(year=Y)
    return next(season for season, (start, end) in seasons
                if start <= x <= end)


def get_holiday():
    return pd.DataFrame([(h,y,z) for (h,d) in zip(holidays['Holiday'], holidays['Date'])
     for (y, z) in zip(df['Date_x'], df['Date_y']) if y.date() <= d.date() if d.date() <= z.date()], columns=['Holiday', 'Date_x', 'Date_y'])


s1 = df['Date_x'].apply(lambda x: get_season(x))
s2 = df['Date_y'].apply(lambda x: get_season(x))
df['Season']= [', '.join(list(set([x,y]))) for (x,y) in zip(s1,s2)]
dft = get_holiday()
dft = dft.groupby(['Date_x', 'Date_y'])['Holiday'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(list(x)))
df = pd.merge(df, dft, how='left', on=['Date_x', 'Date_y'])
df

Out[32]: 
      Date_x     Date_y            Season                     Holiday
0 2020-12-22 2021-01-01            Winter    Christmas, New Years Day
1 2020-06-20 2020-07-11    Summer, Spring                    July 4th
2 2020-02-11 2020-03-27    Spring, Winter              Presidents Day
3 2020-05-22 2020-06-27    Summer, Spring                Memorial Day
```

Comment: This is awesome and exactly what I am trying to do! Although when I replace the dataframe you made with `df = pd.read_csv('dates.csv') i get a StopIteration error on line 23 here:
23     return next(season for season, (start, end) in seasons

Comment: Would NULL values in the data cause this?

Comment: @LarryFlores probably try removing those rows to test it out with `df = df[(df['Date_x'].notnull()) & (df['Date_y'].notnull())`

Comment: Yep, that was the issue, which was actually the main reason I started this thread because I kept getting the same error thinking I was doing something wrong. So when i saw that I got the same error with your sample I figured it maybe was just the NULL values. Either way, thank you so much for all your time, effort, and help, I truly appreciate it more than you know. This has been bugging me for some time.

Comment: No problem @LarryFlores NULLS and Duplicates are the root of much evil that is out there in the data world... I have learned this lesson MANY times, so that's a key thing to look for when cleaning data for future.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for something like below. Notice that part of this solution uses the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139306/determine-season-given-timestamp-in-python-using-datetime).

You may have to adjust to account for your exclusive requirement, but this will give you the idea.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import holidays # pip install holidays

from datetime import date, datetime

us_holidays = holidays.UnitedStates()

Y = 2000 # dummy leap year to allow input X-02-29 (leap day)
seasons = [('winter', (date(Y,  1,  1),  date(Y,  3, 20))),
           ('spring', (date(Y,  3, 21),  date(Y,  6, 20))),
           ('summer', (date(Y,  6, 21),  date(Y,  9, 22))),
           ('autumn', (date(Y,  9, 23),  date(Y, 12, 20))),
           ('winter', (date(Y, 12, 21),  date(Y, 12, 31)))]

def get_season(dt):
    if isinstance(dt, datetime):
        dt = dt.date()
    dt = dt.replace(year=Y)
    return next(season for season, (start, end) in seasons
                if start <= dt <= end)

def get_holiday(data):
    return ",".join([us_holidays.get(x) for x in us_holidays[data["Date_X"] : data["Date_Y"]]])

np.random.seed(0)
rng_x = pd.date_range('2020-12-22', periods=365, freq='D')
rng_y = pd.date_range('2020-12-26', periods=365, freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Date_X': rng_x, 'Season_X': "", 'Date_Y': rng_y, 'Season_Y': ""}) 
print(df.head())

df['Season_X'] = df["Date_X"].apply(get_season)
df['Season_Y'] = df["Date_Y"].apply(get_season)
print(df.head())

df['Holiday'] = df.apply(get_holiday, axis=1)
print(df.head())
```

Output:

```
      Date_X Season_X     Date_Y Season_Y        Holiday
0 2020-12-22   winter 2020-12-26   winter  Christmas Day
1 2020-12-23   winter 2020-12-27   winter  Christmas Day
2 2020-12-24   winter 2020-12-28   winter  Christmas Day
3 2020-12-25   winter 2020-12-29   winter  Christmas Day
4 2020-12-26   winter 2020-12-30   winter
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your columns to datetime type (if they aren't already) and construct two new empty columns:

```
df.Date_x = pd.to_datetime(df.Date_x)
df.Date_y = pd.to_datetime(df.Date_y)
```

Adding the Season column is easy once you notice the `quarter` attribute of datetime Series:

```
df['Season'] = df.Date_x.dt.quarter.map({1: 'Spring', 2: 'Summer', 3: 'Fall', 4: 'Winter'})
```

Holidays are obviously a bit more involved.  Start with an empty column:

```
df['Holiday'] = ''
```

Easter is a special one, let's take care of that first.  Pandas has it built in, though you can define your own Holiday rules too.

```
easter = df.Date_y - pd.tseries.offsets.Easter()
```

That gives you the Easter before `Date_y` (I could have used `Date_x + Easter()` but you said you wanted it exclusive of `Date_y`).  Then:

```
df.loc[df.Date_x < easter, 'Holiday'] = 'Easter'
```

That puts "Easter" in the rows where the holiday is within `[Date_x, Date_y)`.

I leave it as an exercise for you to create the holiday rules for the rest of your holidays.  Here's some advice on that: [Pandas Time Series Holiday Rule Offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485984/pandas-time-series-holiday-rule-offset)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the Holiday Offset, which will come in handy once I learn more about it. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question